# How many combinations of double sided cards can 4 judges select

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The below scenario was taken from this video on the [America's Got Talent show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dOM9f7nqQ0)

4 judges, each judge picks two double sided cards. One card comes from a yellow pile and the other from a blue pile. Each card contains song names on both sides. The judges display the cards on chosen side. How many total combinations of songs can be displayed?

The contestant claims there are 576 combinations see here: https://youtu.be/3dOM9f7nqQ0?t=82

I assume they obtained this using 4! x 4! = 576. However, I don't think this is correct. There should be more combinations since each card is double sided.

I was thinking something like this:
For blue: 8x6x4x2 = 384
For yellow: 384

For blue and yellow = 384 x 384 = 147456

Dividing by duplicates = 147456/(4!x2!)  = 3072 combinations?

Comment: This is missing some important data. Is the name of the song the same on both sides? What's the difference between the yellow and blue card piles? Why does the judge showing 1 card matter? `How many total combinations of songs can be displayed?` where?

Comment: Yes, song names are different. Does it matter what the difference is between the two piles? For arguments sake, it could blue = jazz songs and yellow = pop songs. Each judge has to show 1 card face up from each pile.. i.e. in the end 8 cards are displayed face up (4 judges display 2 cards each).

Comment: It matters if for ex. blue cards have the same name on both sides while yellow cards have different. Or if there are duplicate names in the yellow cards. Or if there are duplicate names in the yellow and blue card piles.

Comment: You claim that each judge picks 2 cards, one from each pile, and then shows 1 card face up? How are there 8 cards face up then? Shouldn't there be 4? How do they decide which side they show?

Comment: Not sure how much clearer I can make the question. 

For ex: if you are a judge. You will pick a card from the blue pile. And another card from the yellow pile. Both cards are double sided. So the total song choice is 4. You have to select one side from the blue card and another side from the yellow card. i.e. you will have selected 2 (out of 4) songs.